# problem with find query

Tags: cakephp

I have a problem with find query:

```
$userInProjects = $this->Timesheet->RegularPost->UserInProject->find('all', array('conditions' => array('UserInProject.user_id' => $id)));
```

The result array:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
   (
       [UserInProject] => Array
           (
               [id] => 11
               [project_id] => 3
               [position_id] => 1
               [user_id] => 15
           )

       [Project] => Array
           (
               [id] => 3
               [short_name] => proj1
               [full_name] => project 1
               [start_date] => 2010-01-01
               [end_date] => 2010-05-01
               [agreement_number] => 12/34U/23
               [active] => 1
               [user_id] => 1
           )

       [Position] => Array
           (
               [id] => 1
               [name] => some_name
           )

       [User] => Array
           (
               [id] => 15
               [username] => foo
               [first_name] =>
               [last_name] =>
               [email] => foo@foo.bar
               [active] => 1
               [created] =>
               [modified] =>
           )

       [RegularPost] => Array
           (
               [0] => Array
                   (
                       [id] => 792
                       [date] => 2010-01-01
                       [size] => 0.20000
                       [users_in_project_id] => 11
                   )

               [1] => Array
                   (
                       [id] => 793
                       [date] => 2010-02-01
                       [size] => 0.20000
                       [users_in_project_id] => 11
                   )

               ( and many more ...)

           )

   )

[1] => Array
   (
       [UserInProject] => Array
           (
               [id] => 20
               [project_id] => 3
               [position_id] => 2
               [user_id] => 15
           )

       [Project] => Array
           (
               [id] => 3
               [short_name] => proj1    
               [full_name] => project 1
               [start_date] => 2010-01-01
               [end_date] => 2010-05-01
               [agreement_number] => 12/34U/23
               [active] => 1
               [user_id] => 1
           )

       [Position] => Array
           (
               [id] => 2
               [name] => some_name2
           )

       [User] => Array
           (
               [id] => 15
               [username] => foo
               [first_name] =>
               [last_name] =>
               [email] => foo@foo.bar
               [active] => 1
               [created] =>
               [modified] =>
           )

       [RegularPost] => Array
           (
               [0] => Array
                   (
                       [id] => 836
                       [date] => 2010-01-01
                       [size] => 0.2
                       [users_in_project_id] => 20
                   )

               [1] => Array
                   (
                       [id] => 837
                       [date] => 2010-02-01
                       [size] => 0.3
                       [users_in_project_id] => 20
                   )

               [2] => Array
                   (
                       [id] => 838
                       [date] => 2010-03-01
                       [size] => 0.3
                       [users_in_project_id] => 20
                   )

               ( and many more ...)

           )
   )
)
```

What I want to achive is the array like above but RegularPost with [date] => 2010-02-01 only.
Is there any way to pass the date '2010-02-01' to the RegularPost in this query?

This query doesn't work:

```
$userInProjects = $this->Timesheet->RegularPost->UserInProject->find('all', array('conditions' => array('UserInProject.user_id' => $id, 'RegularPost.date' => '2010-02-01')));
```

1054: Unknown column 'RegularPost.date' in 'where clause'

Please help. :)

Comment: How is `RegularPost` associated? Is it a `hasMany` relationship with `UserInProject` or `hasAndBelongsToMany`? Also, have you turned on debug to at least level 2? HABTM is pulled after the fact, so that could be the cause of your issue.

Comment: If you get that SQL error you should also get the particular query itself that fails. You could have a look at the column names in the actual query and post the full query here as well.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the Containable behaviour:

```
$userInProjects = $this->Timesheet->RegularPost->UserInProject->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array('UserInProject.user_id' => $id),
    'contain' => array(
        'User', 'Position', 'Project',
        'RegularPost' => array(
            'conditions'=> array( 'RegularPost.date' => '2010-02-01' )
         )
    )
));
```

This query tells Cake's ORM to retrieve all `UserInProject` records with the `id` property you supplied in `$id`, as well as all associated `User`, `Position` and `Project` records. Finally, it tells Cake's ORM to retrieve all `RegularPost` records associated with the retrieved `UserInProject` records that have a `date` property equal to `2010-02-01`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it doesn't work.

I have added 
 var $actsAs = array('Containable');
to my model and I used your code.

It still return the array from my question with all RegularPost.
The date isn't passed to the secondary query.

Comment: Ok, it works! ;)

I'm stupid. I have added the code `var $actsAs = array('Containable');` to Timesheet model instead of to UserInProject model. Now it works like a charm. 

Thank you Daniel very, very much! You saved my day.

Comment: Glad it worked out in the end! Containable is such a useful behaviour, you may want to drop it into your `AppModel` definition. I don't know what the performance implications of that is, versus including it per-model, but it's something to consider. =)